# Call remote dll

Tags: c#, .net, vb.net

Which is the best way to call remote dll? Where can i find examples for this?

Thanks!

Comment: question makes no sense...what sort of DLL, COM?

Comment: What do you mean under "remote"? A DLL on another computer?

Answer (score 1):

Did you mean remote code calling?

If so, I think you should look at [Windows Communication Foundation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/netframework/aa663324.aspx).